# Prevent deployment if previous stage deployment condition is set to false in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a build/release pipeline using yaml:

[image]

Here, the first stage is 'Build'. Once Build is complete and succeeded, next stage is 'deploy to ua'. If deployment to ua is complete and succeeded, next stage is 'deploy to prod'.

As shown here, the condition for 'deployment to ua' returned a 'false'. How would I skip deployment to prod if the condition for 'deployment to ua' is false.

[image]

Comment: Do you if the condition is `false` so the stage will be failed instead of skipped?

Comment: Correct. Skip next deployment if condition in previous deployment is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced above scenario, when i set the conditions for the job in stage `deployment to ua`. The job "Deploy Resources-Ip' would be skipped as the condition was false. But the stage `deployment to ua` was evaluated succeeded. And the next stage will continue to run.

The way to fix this is to set [conditions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on stages level instead of jobs level. For below example:

Stage Release B is depend on Release A, and will be  skipped when stage Release A does not succeed(/skipped). Stage Release A will be skipped(instead of the job B is skipped if the condition is set on job level), when the condition is false.

```
stages: 
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - powershell: echo "Stage A"

- stage: Release_A
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded('Build'), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
  - job: B
    steps:
      - powershell: echo "Stage B"

- stage: Release_B
  dependsOn: Release_A
  condition: succeeded('Release_A')
  jobs:
  - job: C
    steps:
      - powershell: echo "Stage C"
```

However if you want to set the conditions on job level. You need to add another job in stage `deployment to ua` to purposely fail the itself(so that the stage will be evaluated failed) when the condition is false.

Hope above helps!